# Issue to start a simple maven project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have to work with Eclipse due to some reasons which is fresh to me.I created a simple dynamic web project using Maven,then I try to run this project with plugin called `tomcat7-maven-plugin`,but each time I run it with command `tomcat7:run`,the console shows `build success` but the project is automatically terminated.This really confused me,because when I deploy it on my
local tomcat, nothing happened.

[image]

Comment: Did you check your tomcat 7 server up and running? Check with following link http://localhost:8080/ Also share the tomcat server log here.

Comment: actually,the tomcat server doesn't launch at all.but I have solved this by adding '<ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>' to force the plugin to run.I guess I created this project with 'jar' not 'war',thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the snippet, I guess the reason is that it tells:

> > Skipping non-war project

This basically means that your maven project does not produce a WAR (packaging=war) hence tomcat plugin has nothing to run.

I think also that it's not really related to Eclipse here (try to run it from the command line and the results will be the same)

Comment: yeah,you let me know the key reason.I have known what this happened,thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool, Feel free to accept the answer if you find it useful then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please restart the eclipse and clean the project. hopefully it will work.

Comment: thanks,I have resolved this,the tomcat cannot find war for my project.